# Convert array_walk from php to java method

Tags: java, php, arrays, iteration, java-stream

There is a function in PHP like this

```
function array_walk(array &$array, callable $callback, $userdata = null): bool {}
```

I want to use this method in Java. Can anyone help me?

For example, I want to convert this function to Java

```
array_walk($result, function (&$value, $key) {
    $value = sprintf('%s/%s', $key, $value);
});
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { array[i] = someCalculation(array[i]); }`

Comment: thank for your answer . but what is someCalculation in here ?

Comment: Can you provide us what the PHP function `array_walk` does? There are not a large amount people who are familiar both with Java and PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched out what does this method do at [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_array_walk.asp) and I can clearly say that for this purpose the Java 8 Stream API takes the place using the `forEach()`:

```
String[] a = {"blue", "red"};
Stream.of(a).forEach(i -> System.out.println("This is a " + i + " color."));
```

Results in:

```
This is a blue color.
This is a red color.
```

You can also implement your one which does exactly you want using  [@FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). However you cannnot use it since you are stucked in Java 7 and earlier. In this case you have to use the ordinary `for-loop` or the very own class and `@Override` the implementation:

```
public class ArrayWalker<T> {

    T[] t;

    public ArrayWalker(T[] t) {
        this.t = t; 
    }

    public void function(T t) {}

    public ArrayWalker<T> walk() {
        for (int i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
            function(t[i]);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new ArrayWalker<String>(array) {
    @Override
    public void function(String str) {
        System.out.println("This is a " + str + " color.");
    }
}.walk();
```

It will result in the same output as the example above.

Comment: thank for your answer . any idea to use this method in java 1.7 ?

Comment: You could simplify the stream to `Stream.of(a).forEach(...)`